# Why Date.parse() methods works for invalid string "foo 01.01.01"

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a doubt regarding the javascript Date.parse method, below is my code example

```
var dateString = "foo 01.01.01";
Date.parse(dateString)
```

this returns the value as (978287400000) but I expect a NaN so that I can perform an Invalid date check like below.

```
isNaN(dateString.getTime())
```

My question is how the above string is a valid date string? As per MDN link below it should return NaN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Do you get the same result on different browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the page you link to:

> A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (**other formats may be used**, but results may be unexpected).

From [the spec that page links to](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse):

> If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.